# VSIX Installer "This Extension is not installable on any currently installed products."

Tags: c#, visual-studio, vsix

I found many similar problems while looking for a solution, but in every other case, the problem appeared to be that the user was using the wrong version of visual studio.

> 2/6/2022 12:29:06 AM - Microsoft VSIX Installer
> 2/6/2022 12:29:06 AM - -------------------------------------------
> 2/6/2022 12:29:06 AM - vsixinstaller.exe version:
> 2/6/2022 12:29:06 AM - 17.0.5226-preview5
> 2/6/2022 12:29:06 AM - -------------------------------------------
> 2/6/2022 12:29:06 AM - Command line parameters:
> 2/6/2022 12:29:06 AM - C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\ServiceHub\Services\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Service\VSIXInstaller.exe,C:\Users\Foster\Downloads\VersionChanger.vsix
> 2/6/2022 12:29:06 AM - -------------------------------------------
> 2/6/2022 12:29:06 AM - Microsoft VSIX Installer
> 2/6/2022 12:29:06 AM - -------------------------------------------
> 2/6/2022 12:29:06 AM - Initializing Install...
> 2/6/2022 12:29:06 AM - Extension Details...
> 2/6/2022 12:29:06 AM -  Identifier         : VersionChanger.315c8ff9-932e-4b23-b9d8-0fcd23bdb0be
> 2/6/2022 12:29:06 AM -  Name               : Version Changer
> 2/6/2022 12:29:06 AM -  Author             : DSoft Developments
> 2/6/2022 12:29:06 AM -  Version            : 2.3.2
> 2/6/2022 12:29:06 AM -  Description        : Visual Studio extension that allows you to change the version number of all projects in a solution in a easy to user interface.
> 2/6/2022 12:29:06 AM -  Locale             : en-US
> 2/6/2022 12:29:06 AM -  MoreInfoURL        : [https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/554c35ef-fe76-4138-b60e-a44b72ade70e\](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/554c35ef-fe76-4138-b60e-a44b72ade70e%5C)
> 2/6/2022 12:29:06 AM -  InstalledByMSI     : False
> 2/6/2022 12:29:06 AM -  SupportedFrameworkVersionRange : [4.6,)
> 2/6/2022 12:29:06 AM - 
> 2/6/2022 12:29:06 AM -  SignatureState     : Unsigned
> 2/6/2022 12:29:06 AM -  Supported Products : 
> 2/6/2022 12:29:06 AM -      Microsoft.VisualStudio.Community
> 2/6/2022 12:29:06 AM -          Version : [15.0,17.0)
> 2/6/2022 12:29:06 AM -          ProductArchitecture : x86
> 2/6/2022 12:29:06 AM -      Microsoft.VisualStudio.Pro
> 2/6/2022 12:29:06 AM -          Version : [15.0,17.0)
> 2/6/2022 12:29:06 AM -          ProductArchitecture : x86
> 2/6/2022 12:29:06 AM -      Microsoft.VisualStudio.Enterprise
> 2/6/2022 12:29:06 AM -          Version : [15.0,17.0)
> 2/6/2022 12:29:06 AM -          ProductArchitecture : x86
> 2/6/2022 12:29:06 AM - 
> 2/6/2022 12:29:06 AM -  References         : 
> 2/6/2022 12:29:06 AM -  Prerequisites      : 
> 2/6/2022 12:29:06 AM -      -------------------------------------------------------
> 2/6/2022 12:29:06 AM -      Identifier   : Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.CoreEditor
> 2/6/2022 12:29:06 AM -      Name         : Visual Studio core editor
> 2/6/2022 12:29:06 AM -      Version      : [15.0,)
> 2/6/2022 12:29:06 AM -
> 2/6/2022 12:29:06 AM - Signature Details...
> 2/6/2022 12:29:06 AM -  Extension is not signed.
> 2/6/2022 12:29:06 AM -
> 2/6/2022 12:29:06 AM - Searching for applicable products...
> 2/6/2022 12:29:06 AM - Found installed product - Global Location
> 2/6/2022 12:29:06 AM - Found installed product - Visual Studio Community 2022
> 2/6/2022 12:29:06 AM - VSIXInstaller.NoApplicableSKUsException: This extension is not installable on any currently installed products.
> at VSIXInstaller.ExtensionService.GetInstallableDataImpl(IInstallableExtension extension, String extensionPackParentName, Boolean isRepairSupported, IStateData stateData, IEnumerable`1& skuData)\ at VSIXInstaller.ExtensionService.GetInstallableData(String vsixPath, String extensionPackParentName, Boolean isRepairSupported, IStateData stateData, IEnumerable`1& skuData)
> at VSIXInstaller.ExtensionPackService.IsExtensionPack(IStateData stateData, Boolean isRepairSupported)
> at VSIXInstaller.ExtensionPackService.ExpandExtensionPackToInstall(IStateData stateData, Boolean isRepairSupported)
> at VSIXInstaller.App.Initialize(Boolean isRepairSupported)
> at VSIXInstaller.App.Initialize()
> at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
> at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
> at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Telemetry.WindowsErrorReporting.WatsonReport.GetClrWatsonExceptionInfo(Exception exceptionObject)\

as far as I can tell, I am using the correct version. I just installed Visual Studio for the first time, and the version I downloaded appears to be 17.0 according to Microsoft's website. I've tried reinstalling, repairing, and restarting my computer but nothing has worked.

EDIT: I installed VS 2019 and It seems to have fixed my issue for now, but I would still prefer to be using VS 2022; is the version wrong afterall in a way I can't see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extension you installed works with `Visual Studio 2017, 2019`, and from the stack trace:

> Found installed product - Visual Studio Community 2022

So either install visual studio 2017/2019, or use [this version](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Newky2k.VersionChanger2022), which works with visual studio 2022.